# How to show thumbnails in lightbox2 overlay?

Tags: javascript, lightbox, lightbox2

I am trying to show the thumbnails of an image set in the overlay of lightbox2 (https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

In the overlay only one image is being displayed, the one I clicked on. Since it is possible to navigate through the image set, I guess it should also be possible to show the thumbnails, but can't find any advice how to implement this. Can anyone help out?